# How to make model fields observable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, state-management, flutter-getx

I have a model called category , which has two fields, User has a list of categories and what to update the category name, for State Management getx is used

```
class Category {
 
 String? categoryName;
 bool status;
 
 Category(this.categoryName,this.status);
}
```

I have a observable list called catList which is used in List widget

```
var catList = <Category>[].obs;
```

when I update the category field it doest not update

```
catList[index].categoryName = categoryChangedName.value;
```

but If I update the item in object and then assign the object to catList then It changed

```
catList[index] = Category(categoryChangedName.value, catList[index].status );
```

My question is how to make model fields observable, if we have more fields changes then this is not proper way.

Answer (score 3):

As of GetX documentation you need to update values using method and call update(); method inside custom object !

Ex:

```
class Controller extends GetxController {
  int counter = 0;
  void increment() {
    counter++;
    update(); // look here!
  }
}
```

Your use case might be like....

```
class Category {
 
   String? categoryName;
   bool status;
 
   Category(this.categoryName,this.status);
   
   void updateCategoryName(name){
     this.categoryName = name;
     update();
   }
  }

  //Use like..

 catList[index].updateCaetgoryName = categoryChangedName.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

simply use the ***refresh()*** method to update the object after modifying its fields, like this:

```
catList[index].categoryName = categoryChangedName.value;
catList[index].refresh();
```